# VBA Getting data from multiselect listbox and saving them in other excel file in column with today date

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Firstly I will tell you what I am trying to do and what I have already done.
I got two files: MSS -  where from I get data to my listbox and where I want to have the output of selected items in listbox and second where I have userform.
I already accomplish getting data to listbox and multiselecting it:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\plkmxm08\Desktop\MMS.xlsm;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"
    rst.Open "SELECT [LINE], [TASK] FROM fff ORDER BY [LINE];", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst
    i = 0
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = rst![Line]
        .List(i, 1) = rst![TASK]
        i = i + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

It's working fine except the problem with the heading. Even when I change in ListBox properties ColumnHeads to True there is blank space. I selected my area fff with the heading. But I can live without it.

I get the big problem with getting the selected data values.
In MSS file there are two important columns: LINE and TASK, after that I get columns with a date in format yyyy/mm/dd.

So what I what to do is: when a value in listbox is selected I click on the commandbutton. Then excel search today's date in MSS file and in columns LINE and TASK search for text that it's the same as selected in listbox. When it finds this two values: in the column with the correct date and row with correct value write something like "ok" and delete this values from listbox.

What is important: Values that have been already checked this day should not to be imported to listbox with another opening of the excel file. After 6 AM every day, the program should import everything again.

It's very complicated so I hope you will understand what I meant.

I find some way to get what I want but I have some troubles now with one thing.
Here is my code:

```
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LDate As Date
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim lItem As Long, lRows As Long, lCols As Long
Dim bSelected As Boolean
Dim lColLoop As Long, lTransferRow As Long
Dim Val As Variant
Dim MDate As Date

If Time > TimeValue("00:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
    LDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
Else
    LDate = Now
End If
    MDate = DateValue(LDate)

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\plkmxm08\Desktop\MMS.xlsm;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"
rst.Open "SELECT [LINE], [TASK], [Frequency] FROM button ORDER BY [TASK];", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic

lCols = ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
lRows = ListBox1.ListCount - 1

'Ensure they have at least 1 row selected
    For lItem = 0 To lRows
        'At least 1 row selected
        If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            'Boolean flag
            bSelected = True
            'Exit for loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

At least 1 row selected
    If bSelected = True Then
         For lItem = 0 To lRows
             If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) = True Then 'Row selected
                    'Loop through columns of selected row
                    For lColLoop = 1 To lCols
                       'Transfer selected row to relevant row of transfer range
                        Val = ListBox1.List(lItem, lColLoop)
                        rst.Find "TASK = '" & Val & "'"

                        ListBox1.Selected(lItem) = False
                    Next lColLoop
                End If
            Next
       End If
    End Sub`
```

So now if I check any value in the listbox it will find this value in different excel file. 
My problem is that I need to get row index of this cell and column index where is today's date. 
I will be very thankful if someone shows me the right direction.